# How to shrinkwrap horizontally centered div

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this:

```
<container div>
    <header></header>
    <footer>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        <div>
    </footer>
</container div>
```

The footer is a centered sticky footer. I want to add social media icons, but I don't want to specify a specific width.

How do I shrinkwrap the footer `div` without losing it's centered position?
If I add `inline:block` to the `div css`, the centering gets lost and it is aligned to the left side of the browser window.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "shrinkwrap" - is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/c0odznc8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an `inline-block` to the inner `div` you will lose the centering, but you can solve this if you add a `text-align: center` to the footer.

Another solution is to use a `CSS3 transform`. (You have used one in the header).
When you use percents in a `CSS transform` the percent is related to the element itself instead to the element's container. Look at the next snippet:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

footer#social {
  background: #F00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer id="social">
  <div id="socmed">
    <nav id="social" class="socialIndex">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="mailto:info@site.nl">mail </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/anonymous/">linkedin</a></li>
        <li><a href="tel:xx-xxx-xxx-xxx">telephone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I've used the transform part, and that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. I am glad to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 'inline-block', like this:

```
footer > div {display: inline-block;}
```